# How to insert Date in same format as in input into oracle through sqlldr

Tags: oracle, date, sql-loader, controlfile

I have created a .ctl file to insert some data in oracle 11g. In the input file there is column called LAST_DATE having format (MM/DD/YYYY) and same column is there in oracle with date datatype.
But when i try to insert the data its format get changed automatically from (MM/DD/YYYY)  or (04/25/2016) to (DD/MM/YYYY)  or (25-04-2016).
How can I solve this problem. I also define its format in my ctl file TRAILING NULLCOLS
(LAST_DATE DATE "MM/DD/YYYY").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DATE` columns do not have a format. The tool you're using to *examine* the database, however, may have a default format it uses to display `DATE` columns. For example, in PL/SQL Developer the date format used to display date values is in the Preferences dialog in the NLS Options page of the User Interface section. Best of luck.

Comment: It is now DD-MM-RR so if i changed it to MM/DD/YYYY will the data save as MM/DD/YYYY in db.

Comment: @AshiqueSheikh - read the first sentence again. Date columns do not have a format. Dates are not saved as MM/DD/YYYY or anything else, they have an internal representation, and your client decides how to show that value in a readable format. If you change your client setting then subsequent queries will show the values in that format (if you don't override it with `to_char()`).